# Problem with regex detecting $<name>

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, cocoa-touch, nsregularexpression

I am trying to detect the following expression: $

for example

```
$john
```

or

```
$mike
```

What is wrong with my regex?

```
//Check for $symbol
    NSRegularExpression *symbolRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"($[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)" 
                                                                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                                                                error:nil];
    matches = [symbolRegex matchesInString:labelText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [labelText length])];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in matches) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"symbol://%@",[labelText substringWithRange:result.range]]];
        [bodyLabel addCustomLink:url inRange:[result range]];        
    }

    [symbolRegex release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to escape the $.

```
(\\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
```

> **$ (dollar)**
>
> Matches at the end of the string the regex pattern is applied to.
>   Matches a position rather than a character. Most regex flavors have an
>   option to make the dollar match before line breaks (i.e. at the end of
>   a line in a file) as well. Also matches before the very last line
>   break if the string ends with a line break.

Since it's a special/reserved character, it needs to be escaped.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: I get the compiler warning: Unknown escape sequence '\$'

Comment: You have to escape the backslash. Try \\$.

Comment: No more warning, but the code is not detecting $john type text

Comment: What does the string look like? Just "$john"? Are you getting an error of any sort?

Comment: There are no matches, so my matches array is empty.